# Insert into two tables does not insert into the last table . pdo

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert into two different tables but the last table does not receive the data. 
There is no error displayed I really do not know what might be the cause of this situation.
Is it because the second table contain a foreign key ?

```
<?php

#connect to the db
require_once('db.inc.php');
?>
<?php

$date_created = date('y-m-d h:i:s a');
$username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? trim($_POST['username']) : '';
$Previllage = (isset($_POST['Previllage'])) ? trim($_POST['Previllage']) : '';
#second tanble values 
$title = (isset($_POST['title'])) ? trim($_POST['title']) : '';
$firstname = (isset($_POST['firstname'])) ? trim($_POST['firstname']) : '';
$lastname = (isset($_POST['lastname'])) ? trim($_POST['lastname']) : '';
$client_code = (isset($_POST['client_code'])) ? trim($_POST['client_code']) : '';
#end
$query = "INSERT INTO tish_user(username,Previllage,date_created)
VALUES(:username,:Previllage,:date_created)";
$insert = $con->prepare($query);
$insert->execute(array(':username' => $username,
    ':Previllage' => $Previllage,
    'date_created' => $date_created));
# try another insert 
$query = "INSERT INTO tish_clientinfor(title,firstname,lastname,client_code,date_registered)
VALUES(:title,:firstname,:lastname,:client_code,:date_registered)";
$insert = $con->prepare($query);
$insert->execute(array(
    ':title' => $title,
    ':firstname' => $firstname,
    ':lastname' => $lastname,
    ':client_code' => $client_code,
    'date_registered' => $date_created));
?>
```

Comment: How should an error be displayed (what ever displayed here means...) if you don't even check for an error?

Comment: And note that there is a colon (`:`) missing in the last query parameters handle (name): `date_registered`. Same with the `date_created` above.

Comment: @humphrey Implement `try` `catch` with `PDOException` as parameter to get error info.

Comment: @DON I di what u said but still : no error not insertion.try {//my all code here }catch (PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}

Comment: @humphrey Update your code with exception handling.

Comment: @humphrey Have you errors to display in `php.ini` ?

Comment: I really do not knw how to do all that: my gtalk kingmusa5 @gmail.com plse invite me Google talk

Comment: even this does not work in mysql query window : INSERT INTO tish_user(username,Previllage)
VALUES("Thabo","Gold");

INSERT INTO tish_clientinfor(title,firstname)
VALUES("Thabo","Gold");

Answer (score 0):

If the "client_code" field in the second query has a foreign key constraint, then i beilieve that is what is causing the query to fail. You can try to echo out the second query and run it in phpmyadmin sql section or in mysql command prompt.

Comment: not its not the foreign key is on update and it atomaticaly update from the first table

Comment: did you try running the query in phpmyadmin or mysql cmd prompt? that can give some leads.

Comment: Yes but also it inserts the first table content not the second 1. remember it has a foreign key  INSERT INTO tish_user(username,Previllage)
VALUES("Thabo","Gold");
INSERT INTO tish_clientinfor(title,firstname)
VALUES("Thabo","Gold");